# Incomplete type is not allowed: stringstream

Tags: c++, types, stringstream

Why does this line give the error `Error: incomplete type is not allowed`?

```
stringstream ss;
```

Comment: What header files have you included?

Comment: I'm guessing there was an `#include<stringstream>` or something I should have used? #include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

Answer (score 270, accepted):

`#include <sstream>` and use the fully qualified name  i.e. `std::stringstream ss;`

Comment: The error is probably due to stringstream being defined as a generic type of something undefined.

Comment: I think visual studio sometimes allows to use stringstream without including the file. Maybe this is the cause of error

Answer (score 64):

Some of the system headers provide a forward declaration of `std::stringstream` without the definition. This makes it an 'incomplete type'. To fix that you need to include the definition, which is provided in the `<sstream>` header:

```
#include <sstream>
```

Answer (score 19):

An `incomplete type` error is when the compiler encounters the use of an identifier that it knows is a type, for instance because it has seen a forward-declaration of it (e.g. `class stringstream;`), but it hasn't seen a full definition for it (`class stringstream { ... };`).

This could happen for a type that you haven't used in your own code but is only present through included header files -- when you've included header files that use the type, but not the header file where the type is defined.  It's unusual for a header to not itself include all the headers it needs, but not impossible.

For things from the standard library, such as the `stringstream` class, use the language standard or other reference documentation for the class or the individual functions (e.g. Unix `man` pages, MSDN library, etc.) to figure out what you need to `#include` to use it and what namespace to find it in if any.  You may need to search for pages where the class name appears (e.g. `man -k stringstream`).