# incomplete type not allowed error, How to fix ?

Tags: c++

I am getting this error

"Incomplete type not allowed"

the line getting this error :

```
Vec3 MaxHeight;
```

Comment: #include the header file where `Vec3` is defined.

Answer (score 1):

you should search first before asking, and you can find the error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781597/incomplete-type-is-not-allowed) and i'm guessing the needed cpp is this in [here](http://healpix.jpl.nasa.gov/html/cxxsupport/classvec3.html)

add

```
#include <vec3.h>
```

to your project

Comment: `Vec3` is a very common name for a class, how do you know the library the OP uses?

Comment: @DyP: What does that matter?  I think it's obvious that the intent is to include the declaration of `vec3`, wherever that may be.  The most logical guess given what the OP has provided is `vec3.h`

Comment: thank you @EdS. just what i was about to say

Comment: Mostly because of "you can find [...] the needed cpp in here". The OP might not use this library and someone downloading it might get confused. If you only guess the name of the header file IMHO you should say so.

Comment: @DyP i've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: There is no #include <vec3.h>

Comment: @DyP: If someone skipped learning the basics of the language and has no clue as to what constitutes a complete type or how to use header files then they aren't going to get very far by coming to SO anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to fix it you have to make `Vec3` a complete type, i.e. you have to *define* it (as opposed to merely *declaring* it).

Note that it is possible that it is not about "including the header file", as the other answers suggest. If you forgot to include the header, the compiler would probably know nothing about `Vec3`. The error message would be different. In your case the compiler knows `Vec3`, but it just happens to be incomplete.

What caused this situation is impossible to tell from what you posted (you essentially posted nothing). If you do include the header file that defined `Vec3`, then the problem might be caused by circular header inclusion or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all the time, I come across this by including one file from the library that declares Vec3, but not including the header that includes Vec3 itself.

This happens because sometimes the other headers "forward declare" Vec3 so they can use in their function definitions, but they don't need a complete definition.